# ¿Python, imprimir un diccionario en columnas?

Tags: python

Como imprimo un diccionario en columnas en Python 3, es decir, tengo por ejemplo este código, que imprime un diccionario con dos listas dentro, la llave es la venta y el valor son los articulos vendidos, al momento del print, como hago para que se vea todo más alineado, como por ejemplo un dataframe de pandas pero en columnas. el problema dice que una venta puede tener uno o mas articulos, por lo que es parecido a un ticket de compra, en el que tienes varios articulos. y aqui piden imprimir en columnas.

```
import pandas as pd
registro_ventas={}
venta_total= []

while True:
    print("\n***MENU***")
    print("1. Registrar una venta")
    print("2. Consultar una venta")
    print("3  Salir")
    opcion = int(input("Ingrese una opcion:  "))

    if opcion == 1:
        respuesta=1
        identificador =int( input ("\nDime un numero identificador para la venta "))
        if identificador in  venta_total:
            print("\nEse identificador ya esta registrado, intenta con otro")
        else:
            while respuesta == 1:
                desc_articulo = input ("\nDime la descripcion del articulo: ")
                piezas_vendidas= int(input("\nDime la cantidad de piezas vendidas: "))
                precio_venta= float(input("\nDime el precio de venta: "))
                monto_total= piezas_vendidas * precio_venta
                print("\nSu monto total a pagar es de $ ",monto_total)
                venta_articulo= [desc_articulo,"  ",piezas_vendidas,"  ",precio_venta,"   ",monto_total]
                venta_total.append(venta_articulo)
                respuesta = int(input("\n ¿Deseas capturar otro articulo? \n(1-Si / 0-No): "))
            registro_ventas[identificador]=[venta_total]
            venta_total=[]
    elif opcion == 2:
        # El identificador debe de ser del mismo dato que el id a buscar para que se
        #Cumpla la condicion.
        id_buscar =int(input("\nDime el identificador de la venta que deseas consultar: "))
        if id_buscar in registro_ventas.keys():
            print("\nLa venta con ese identificador es: ", identificador)
            articulos_ticket=list(registro_ventas[identificador])
            columnas=["Descripcion", "Cantidad" , "Precio venta", "Precio total "]
            print(columnas)
            for articulo in range(0,len(articulos_ticket)+1) : #sumamos 1 porque el limite no se alcanza
                print(articulos_ticket[0][articulo])
        else:
            print("\nLo siento, ese identificador no fue capturado")
    elif opcion == 3:
        break
    else: 
        print("Has introducido una opcion invalida")
```

Answer (score 2):

Lo que pides se resuelve de forma fácil con [Fstrings](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html) (Python 3.6+)

Ahora bien, el diccionario de datos está mas confuso de lo que debería ser, quitando practicidad para guardar la información, lo que a su vez aumenta la complejidad del script.

Originalmente los datos se guardan en el diccionario de la forma:

```
registro_ventas = {id1 : [[[elem1], [elem2], ...]], id2:[[[elem1], [elem2], ...]], ...}
```

Hay una lista anidada que está de más, propongo eliminarla y dejarlo de la forma:

```
registro_ventas = {id1 : [[elem1], [elem2], ...], id2:[[elem1], [elem2], ...], ...}
```

Ahora sería mucho más fácil de agregar datos a ese diccionario y recorrerlo para extraerlos. Para agregar un key (identificador) nuevo junto con su lista padre:

```
registro_ventas[identificador] = []
```

Y luego se le va añadiendo las listas de cada venta con `registro_ventas[identificador].apend(sublista)`

Propongo también que el id de venta sea un string, al igual que las opciones del menú, así te olvidas de hacer validaciones. Pero si quieres que el id sea entero, solo vuelve a agregar el `int()`.

```
registro_ventas = {}

while True:
    print("\n***MENU***")
    print("1. Registrar una venta")
    print("2. Consultar una venta")
    print("3  Salir")
    opcion = input("Ingrese una opcion: ")

    if opcion == '1':
        identificador = input("\nDime un numero identificador para la venta ")
        if identificador in registro_ventas:
            print("\nEse identificador ya esta registrado, intenta con otro")
        else:
            registro_ventas[identificador] = []
            while True:
                desc_articulo = input("Dime la descripcion del articulo: ")
                piezas_vendidas = int(input("Dime la cantidad de piezas vendidas: "))
                precio_venta = float(input("Dime el precio de venta: "))
                monto_total = piezas_vendidas * precio_venta
                print("Su monto total a pagar es de $ ",monto_total)
                registro_ventas[identificador].append([desc_articulo, piezas_vendidas, precio_venta, monto_total])
                respuesta = input("\n¿Deseas capturar otro articulo? (1-Si / 0-No): ")
                if respuesta == '0':
                    break
    elif opcion == '2':
        id_buscar = input("\nDime el identificador de la venta que deseas consultar: ")
        if id_buscar in registro_ventas:
            print("\nLa venta con ese identificador es: ", id_buscar)
            print(f'{"Descripcion":<25} {"Cantidad":^10} {"Precio venta":^10} {"Precio total":>15}')
            print(f'{"-----------":<25} {"--------":^10} {"------------":^10} {"------------":>15}')
            for articulo in registro_ventas[id_buscar]:
                print(f'{articulo[0]:<25} {articulo[1]:^10} {articulo[2]:^10.2f} {articulo[3]:>15.2f}')
        else:
            print("\nLo siento, ese identificador no fue capturado")
    elif opcion == '3':
        break
    else: 
        print("Has introducido una opcion invalida")
```

Un ejemplo de la salida

```
Ingrese una opcion: 2

Dime el identificador de la venta que deseas consultar: 23

La venta con ese identificador es:  23
Descripcion                Cantidad  Precio venta    Precio total
-----------                --------  ------------    ------------
Tornillo acero 12mm           18        1.35              24.30
Pegamento epox                1         4.50               4.50
Lija N400                     6         1.10               6.60
```

Comment: Hola amigo, me pasa un error, esque al momento de buscar el identificador, me imprime otro que no le proporcione, por ejemplo agrego una venta con id 1 y otra con id 2 y si consulto la venta con id 1 me imprime la del id 2

Comment: @HugoLeyva los datos como tal deben estar bien porque pide `id_buscar = input(...)` y luego se busca `registro_ventas[id_buscar]`, no hay forma de que regrese otro registro. Lo que si es que hay un [error] en la linea `print("\nLa venta con ese identificador es: ", identificador)`, lo cual imprimirá cualquier cosa como ID, debe ser `id_buscar`. Ya lo corrijo en el código.

Comment: ya lo corregi amigo muchas gracias no me percate de ese error